# Cannot declare class because its already defined

Tags: php, class

I want to make my own class in php to handle my errors I want to show to the user, for example when the user are logging in but the password or username is false.

I have a map classes with the files:
**errorHandling.class.php**

```
class errorHandling
{

public $customError;

public function setCustomError($error)
{
  $this->customError = $error;
}

public function getCustomError()
{
  echo $this->customError;
}

}
```

And in the **users.class.php** 
when the user try's to login and it fails the else will be like:

```
else {
      include 'errorHandling.class.php';
      $errorHandle =  new errorHandling();
      $errorHandle->setCustomError("Username or password are wrong!");
    }
```

Then in the **login.php** in the root map I have this code to call the function:

```
include 'classes/errorHandling.class.php';
include 'classes/users.class.php';

$errorHandle = new errorHandling();
$errorHandle->getCustomError();
```

Well now I get this error message but I don't understand it so I hope some of you guys can helping me out or give me some tips to improve my class.

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class errorHandling, because the name is already in use in /classes/errorHandling.class.php on line 1
```

Comment: The gist is what Fred told you earlier. Since you are including the file several times, you are redeclaring the same class over and over again. Change to the _once type of declaration every time you include errorHandling.class.php and you should be fine. You said you did, but you probably missed something.

Comment: I checked all the documents, the error is gone now, but the function didn't work.. when I use the right credentials I can login but when it's wrong no error are showing :(

Answer (score -1):

Every time you `include` a file in php, it will be loaded and run. For class definitions, you want to use `require_once`, which as it says, will only be loaded once.

Comment: I have tried to change all the `includes` into `require_once` but I still get that error!